# Selenium and Uploadify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, selenium, uploadify, capybara

Is there any way to usefully test an Uploadify file upload with Selenium?  I'm using Capybara with Rails, but really, *any* solution with Selenium would be a starting place.  I'm worried I may have to disable Uploadify for Selenium testing.

Comment: I'd suggest testing at the controller level with a small file, if you want an upload integration test. Issues with uploaders in my experience are differences in positioning a SWF file (z-index) not firing/handling javascript correctly, but the upload plugin you are using should have resolved those issues for you.

Comment: **Note: A good answer will also show how to actually _select_ a file for Uploadify. So if you want the bounty points please answer to this too**

Comment: The same question on: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4508460/698718

Comment: __The bounty ends in one day; I'd be sad to not be able to award it to anyone. If you know more about this topic please share.__

Comment: Sadly, the bounty ended without any activity.

Comment: Why are you testing the plugin?  Why not let the maintainer worry about that and focus your efforts on testing your own code?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get this to work, by interacting with the JS directly.  I added this to my test helper.

```
def upload_via_uploadify file_input_id, path
  page.execute_script("$('##{file_input_id}').show()")
  attach_file(file_input_id, path)
  page.execute_script("$('##{file_input_id}').uploadifyUpload()")
end
```

You can't actually trigger a button click because of the flash, but besides that it works great and you can test the rest of the interaction goes as planned

Comment: How do I use this code while working selenium - java.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Flash-selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) project. But it uses JS so you possibly could do interactions with Flash by yourself using JS.